# Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'ibeto_hotels.Global'

Tags: c#

Am having issue on my project with the following error:Line 1:

```
 <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="ibeto_hotels.Global" Language="C#" %>.
```

Please, anyone to help with a solution.

Comment: Where is that type defined?

Comment: Post the code for your `Global.asax.cs`.

Comment: Anderson, thank you. I found the error and have rectified it.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, my guess is you added/changed the namespace that holds your `Global` class, inside of `Global.asax.cs`.

Verify that the namespace is `ibeto_hotels`.